# Linearly independence on Kronecker products

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, kronecker-product

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with units. Suppose that $\{A_i \}$ and $\{B_j\}$ are two linearly independent families of $n \times n$ matrices over $R$.

Is it true that the set $\{A_i \otimes B_j \}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: Yes, this follows from basic facts about tensor products.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you. Do you know where I can find a good reference for this? Perhaps a book or a paper. I am not familiar with Tensor products. Thank you again.

Comment: The best reference would be a nice beginners book on Algebra. Dummit and Foote does  nicely for me.